# Formal grammar and arity

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
S --> LR .
L --> aL .
R --> bR .
```

This grammar generates the language a^n b^k, where n,k > 0.
I want a grammar that generates the language a^n b^n where n>0, so
my goal is to obtain a grammar in order to ensure that the number of a is always equal of b, but still keeping the non-terminals L and R.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: By the way, your grammar is not correct. You need productions `L→a` and `R→b`.

Answer (score 0):

In a.*context free* grammar, the derivations of `L` and `R` in  `S → L R` are independent of each other. That is what "context free" means: the derivation of a non-terminal is not affected by the context in which the non-terminal occurs.

So if you want a grammar in which `L` and `R` must derive strings of equal length, it will have to be a context-sensitive grammar. No context-free grammar can do that.

Of course, there is a simple CFG for the language:

```
S →
S → a S b
```